Flow assignment not populating field
So I have a flow that assigns values to create records and it appears that all but one field assignment is not working/populating despite the assignment correctly appearing in the debug log.
The assignment:

Expected behavior: Record field Account Ref ID should populate with value 59
The debug log showing correct assignment of the variable:

Then in the create records debug details, the field assignment is completely missing from the individual record itself.  All the other create records elements work just fine with the exact same setup except for this one.  (Sorry couldn't include a screenshot here since it has confidential data)
Anyone run into a similar issue where a field assignment disappears when flow  creates records?   Seems weird the other assignments work just fine.

May I know the field type for the EntryLine.QBO_Account_Ref_ID__c field ?

It is a number field

Seems the assignment action is correct. Please check whether you're having any apex based actions or any field update available based on that field like it's revert the field assignment during flows (in before save) action.
